# Q1 2021 Drug Event Endpoint Update

Tags: openfda

It looks like the Q1 2021 FAERS release was posted on 10-May-2021. Does anyone know when openFDA will refresh its Drug Event endpoint to include the new data? I know this typically occurs once a week, so hopefully soon?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The Q1 2021 FAERS release has just been added to openFDA.